# When I edit first element in Arraylist, second edit too

Tags: java, arraylist

I replace elements of Arraylist by using this code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<int[]> col = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new int[]{11, 122}, new int[]{92, 324}, new int[]{24, 56}));
        for (int i = col.size() - 1; i != 0; i--) {
            col.set(i,col.get(i-1));
        }
        col.get(0)[0] -= 32;
    }
```

I want to print new elements of Arraylist, but I got {[-21, 122],[-21, 122],[92, 324]}. I want to print {[-21, 122],[11, 122],[92, 324]}. How can I do this?

Comment: `col.set(i,col.get(i-1))` is copy one element *which is an array reference* to another. You then have two elements which refer to the same array. However you modify that array, you'll see the change whether you get to it via one element or the other. It's not clear why you've got that loop in the first place, to be honest.

Comment: Can I replace the element and dont copy?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. It doesn't help that you haven't explained what you're trying to achieve. But it's really important that you understand how reference types work in Java, and that a `List` in Java *always* contains references.

Comment: You can *not* call `List.set`, and instead do `col.get(i)[0] = col.get(i-1)[0]; col.get(i)[1] = col.get(i-1)[1];` But it isn't clear from your question what you want to do.